# Getting Started template Sitecore 10- running up.ps1 - failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0

Tags: installation, docker

Trying to do local Sitecore 10 setup using [Getting Started Template](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/101/developer-tools/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html).

While running up.ps1 getting error

*failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform in manifest sha256:3c0ca16693dfc1252120cb6066ddfccf53b9bbce4523bdb7c7fb3f55dd86f33f: not found*

[image]

Please assist.

Comment: Make sure Docker Desktop is set to Windows Containers and not Linux.... also first result in google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68984133/error-failed-to-solve-with-frontend-dockerfile-v0-failed-to-create-llb-definit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to explain fix for this issue which may assist other.

Thanks @Richerd Seal for providing suggestion.

If yours docker desktop running on linux containers then will get this issue.

We have to switch to window container.

click on docker icon on toolbar, right click and switch to window container.

[image]